# Python decompiler for Eclipse PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, decompiler

Is there a way to get eclipse to read .pyc files?

I'm trying to avoid downloading an external program and I would rather not trust an on-line service.

Comment: PyDev doesn't really have it, but take a look at: possible duplicate of [Free Python decompiler that is not an online service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211/free-python-decompiler-that-is-not-an-online-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no open-source/free decompiler for Python - just a "disassembler" (see the [dis-module](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) in the stdlib). Getting back from the Python Stack-VM-assembly (which is stored in .pyc-files) to working Python code is *mostly* easy, as the general structure of the code is preserved, even when using "-O".

For special case solutions (i.e., marshalling .pyc-s in the old [pre 2.3]-format), see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211/free-python-decompiler-that-is-not-an-online-service) @FabioZadrozny linked, but especially when you're using Python >=2.5 to produce the .pyc-s, this will most probably not work, though, as a lot of opcodes have changed/been added.